# Load Assembly from Embedded Resources at run time inside Library Project

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I am writing DLL project, and I need to use an external DLL inside it, and to include this external DLL in my DLL eventually.
I added to the embedded resources of the project this DLL file and I tried to link to the "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve" event - function that loads the dll from embedded resources, But, I still get the message "*Could not load file or assembly ... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified*"
I emphasize that I wrote the binding event row ("*AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=....*") and the linked function inside the DLL project, and not in project that uses my DLL,

So is it OK behavior? why still I get this Exception?

And if it is not a good scenario, how can I use external DLL inside DLL project?

Code: (inside of my library project)

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MY_EXTERNAL_DLL_PLACED_IN_EMBEDDED_RESOURCES"))
            {
                return Assembly.Load(StreamToBytes(stream));
            }
        }

static byte[] StreamToBytes(Stream input)
        {
            var capacity = input.CanSeek ? (int)input.Length : 0;
            using (var output = new MemoryStream(capacity))
            {
                int readLength;
                var buffer = new byte[4096];

                do
                {
                    readLength = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, readLength);
                }
                while (readLength != 0);

                return output.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't load a DLL from a resource.

Comment: Please post a minimal code that demonstrates the issue. Look in the exception as well, there should be a fusion log property which might have more information as to why

Comment: I added code, and in the exception I don't see something that gives me more information, I see just the DLL name and version

Comment: I saw that in the Exception there is more data: it tried to find the Assembly in the "bin/debug" folder of the project that uses my DLL project, so I tried to copy this assembly to there and to load the assembly from there, but still it doesn't work!! Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the assembly and then use IlMerge (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to combine the referenced assembly back into yours.